# mapping apiendpoint with controller methods in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, endpoint

I am new to ASP.NET and I'm following a course and I found the instructor in some places calls the api endpoint ends with the method name in the controller like below :

```
$.post("/api/notifications/markAsRead")
```

where the method in the controller is like below :

```
public IHttpActionResult MarkAsRead()
        {
           // some code here
           return OK()
        }
```

but in other places I found the instructor  called the
api without the name of the method like so :

```
$.post("/api/followings", { "FolloweeId": btn.attr("data-user-id") })
```

where the related method in the controller is :

```
public IHttpActionResult Follow(FollowingDto dto)
        {
            // some code here
            return Ok();
        }
```

Please explain the diffrence between both cases and why the endpoint is different ?
to be more clear my problem is that i think the endpoint should be `/api/followings/follow` ending by follow just like the first example was `/api/notifications/markAsRead`  ending by markasread

Comment: Sometimes you want to send some information along with the HTTP request. In such cases, you pass them as your instructor did ```{ "FolloweeId": btn.attr("data-user-id") }```

Comment: @DaniyarAubekerov that is not what I am asking about ,my problem is that i think the endpoint should be /api/followings/follow just like the first example was /api/notifications/markAsRead

Comment: @ibrahimmorsiblacktiger you can decorate your controller's action methods with specific HTTP attributes like **[HttpPost]**. So, in this case, you don't need to include the method name if you are sending a post request it will map automatically. Just one exception, it will only work if there is only one post method in your controller or you have to specify the method name otherwise.

Comment: @AribYousuf so this is optional i can use one of these endpoints based on my prefrence

Comment: @ibrahimmorsiblacktiger Yes but make sure if you have more than one post request method in your controller then you have to specify the method name as well.